# Unbind Error for SlingRepository in Bundles created in CRXDE Lite

Tags: java, annotations, aem, jdk1.7

I am trying to use:

```
@Reference
private SlingRepository repo;
```

in a java Service that I create in CRXDE Lite in cq5.6.1. When I try to build this bundle it the jar is created successfully without any errors. But when the service runs I see the following error in my logs:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 13 
    in methodpack.age.name.unbindRepo(Lorg/apache/sling/jcr/api/SlingRepository;)V
```

I have read in the below post that someone had a similar problem but could not find the solution. I did try using the `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier` in the start command of the AEM instance but to no success did it help.

Note: I did not start a new instance with that command. I only started the already established instance.

Also adding the unbind method explicitly does not seem like a valid solution.

Now this has definitely something to do with the JAVA version because our service is running smoothly with JAVA1.6 installed machine but gives the above error in JAVA 1.7.

Comment: why adding the unbind method explicitly is not a valid solution?